# How do I change the background of a site with a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, background

I'm trying to coding a site where I need to change the background with a button, but I can't...

I created a button that changes the color of the background while clicking a button but after I added an image as a background, it doesn't want to change the color background (obviously)...

```html
<head>
<style>
:root{
   --main-bg: url(https://www.the url of my bg.jpg);

}
</style> // creating a variable for the bg of my site

<style>
body {
   background: var(--main-bg) repeat-x;

}
</style> // using this variable

<script>
      var colors = ["#2d2d2d", "#f2f2f2"];
      var colorIndex = 0;
      function changeColor() {
          var col = document.getElementById("body");
          if( colorIndex >= colors.length ) {
              colorIndex = 0;
          }
          col.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
          colorIndex++;
// the js script to change the bg color
      }
  </script>

<script>
      function backgroundHiding() {
         let root = document.documentElement;

         root.addEventListener("onclick", e => {
            if (--main-bg) =  "#2d2d2d" {
            root.style.setProperty('--main-bg', " url(https://www.the urlof my bg.jpg)")
         } else {
            root.style.setProperty('--main-bg', "#2d2d2d")
         }
            // the js script to hide my img bg
      }
      </script>

<div class="button">
      <body id='body'>
            <button onclick="changeColor(); backgroundHiding();" class="lightbutton"><span>Turn On/Off the lights</span> </button>

</div> // creating the button that interact with the two js functions
</head>
```

I expected that it works but... huh... no
It works sometimes, like 1 time every 100 times, I don't know why...
If someone could help me, I would really appreciate it!

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ppvsvl?embed=1&file=index.html
```

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] in a runnable snippet or https://stackblitz.com/?

Comment: @Oram here it is, I added the stackblitz so you can see what happens

Comment: @Oram idk how to embed it but if you want to help me embedding the stackblitz, I would appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need additional event listener:

```
root.addEventListener("onclick", e => {...})
```

The second, as I get it, you are trying to read the CSS variable and compare it in **if** statement. This won't work:

```
if (--main-bg) =  "#2d2d2d"
```

I've fixed it here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-crl57k?file=index.html

Does it look like what you wanted to do?

Comment: YES!!! Thank you soooo much!!! I don't really understand what you did (because I don't really know how to code in JS) but this works 100 times better than what I did!

Answer (score 0):

Try my project setBackgroundCanvas it allows for jpegs, if your using npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/element-functions-set_background_canvas